# What does the 何も mean in the bolded positive sentence?

Tags: translation, negation

While translating the bolded sentence in the following paragraph, I find myself unable to translate the 何も, as my genki textbook, the [online dictionary I am using](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BD%95%E3%82%82), and the online textbook I am using all say that 何も is used in negative sentences, or only give translations for it's use in negative sentences only.

> 体力も神経も使い果たし、疲{つか｝れ果てて泥｛どろ｝のように眠｛ねむ｝る毎日が続く。
> 余計なことを考える暇｛ひま｝もなければ、夢を見ることもない。やがて、そ
> んな生活に慣れはじめると、今度は物事をじっくりと考えることが苦痛になってきた。そ**の時々の課題をクリアすることに、全力で取り組んでいる間は、何も思い悩｛なや｝んだりせずにすむ。**

I'm ninety percent certain the bolded sentence isn't being negated, so how do I go about translating a 何も in a positive sentence?

Comment: You say you're 90% certain it isn't negative but what about the せずに part?

Comment: @user3856370 Hold up, hold up, the adverb せずに is negating the sentence?

Comment: Not the whole sentence, just the 何も思い悩んだりせずに part = "without (doing things like) worrying about anything"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that 何も is a [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74377/5010) that means "(not) at all". But you seem to have missed せず is a **negative** verb that roughly means しないで.

- [せず - What does it come from?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29734/5010)
- [What is the difference between the negative forms -ず and -ぬ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235/5010)
- [JLPT N2 Grammar: ずに済む](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB%E6%B8%88%E3%82%80-zu-ni-sumu-meaning/)

> その時々の課題をクリアすることに、全力で取り組んでいる間は、**何も**思い悩なやんだりせずにすむ。
> As long as you put all your energy into completing the task at hand, you don't have to worry about anything **at all**.