# What is the meaning of って, っけ and んでした in this phrase “完のゲームって、どうなったんでしたっけ”

Tags: colloquial-language, particle-って

Context:
I found this phrase in the comment section while I was seeing a video regarding the new switch version of Oregairu Zoku.

Questions:
I grasped the meaning of this phrase, that should be something along the lines of “What happened to the game of Kan?” Or at least this is what I think.

However, I have a few doubts:

1. って, from what I know, equals to the particle と in casual conversation, but what does it mean in this phrase, what is it quoting? Is it used instead of は or as some kind of contraction?
2. Here んでした is the past form of のだ?
   Why is it used in the past form? And what is its meaning in this case? (is it used just to add emphasis and to show the curiosity of the speaker towards the answer of the question?)
3. っけ From what I know it means that you are trying to remember or recollecting something… Is it used to show that he’s thinking back when he saw the release date, the video or the news regarding the game?
   What is its nuance here?
   And if the phrase means “What happened to the video game?” isn’t it the same of “完のゲームって、どうなったの”?

P.S. This is my first post on this site, so I want to apologize in case there are mistakes, the title is wrong, the message’s body is too short/long/poorly shaped, etc.

Comment: Related: (1) [Understanding 人ってオーラって言うじゃない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57276/43676), (2&3) [Why is it that the っけ suffix can only be attached to a question-sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1878/43676)

Comment: This is also related (2&3): [What does the "だった" in "だったっけ" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21000/43676)

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you for sending me those links. What I want to understand now is if my comprehension of this のでした is right. I read that japanese people often tend to end  sentences with の/んだっけ、の/んだったっけ to express "The thing I forgot is ..." using this I got a decent translation “The thing I forgot (past form of のでした) is how it(the game) turned  out” which still sounds weird to me, but (at least for me) it means something “I cannot remember what was the state of the game when I saw it, when I read about it, when I heard about it, etc.” so he is implicitly asking someone to give him this info.

Comment: Has this translation the same or a similar meaning of the Japanese one?     Is there a more literal translation that could help me to understand the real meaning and how all these different words fit together? 
Because when I try to translate the past form of のでした “the thing was” I cannot succeed in formulating a decent translation “(I cannot remember) the thing that was how it (the game) turned out” which is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

って is often used in casual speech to start commenting on or asking about something. It plays a similar function to は but doesn’t have the contrastive sense of は.

In plain style, the following are both possible.

> どうなったんだっけ

> どうなったんだったっけ

Though they are practically interchangeable, there is a slight nuance. The second sounds like the speaker is simply wondering or trying to remember a conclusion that was already made in the past, whereas the first could be used, depending on context, to ask about, or ask for, a pending decision, as when spoken by a boss to demand reporting from a subordinate.

In polite style, however, only the past tense sounds natural.

> x どうなったんですっけ

> どうなったんでしたっけ

どうなったの is the plain version of どうなったんですか and is a direct question to the listener. っけ makes it sound like the speaker is half wondering to his/herself and half expecting an answer from the listener.

> 完のゲームって、どうなったんでしたっけ。
> I wonder what(ever) happened to the game of Kan. (Do you know?)

In this context, it is not necessarily the case that the speaker forgot something he/she once learned about the game. It could as well be that he/she simply doesn’t know.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. 
I think I’ve finally understood how these words fit together

Answer (score -2):

1. Yes. The first part could be translate as, "Like, at the beginning of the game", with the quotive emphasizing the earlier part.
2. No. A translation could be "what way - was - that being the case - to have done." With the phrase you highlighted being the last two parts.
3. Yes, ke is an ending that indicates a question, similar to the sentence ending phrase "idk" in English.

So, tying it together:
"Like, at the beginning of the game, I only kinda remember what was going on."

But based on context you might also get:
"I only kinda remember what to do."

Comment: Where did “at the beginning” come from? And why “what to do”?